# How to use nested data in model class using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have data like ug.tutionfees andpg.tutionfees in MongoDB. How to implement this data in NodeJS model class and angular plz tell me.

My model class:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UniversitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    worldranking:String,
    countryranking:String,
    universityname:String,
    bachelorprogram:String,
    masterprogram:String,
    phdprogram:String,
    country:String
},{collection:'us'});

const University =module.exports = mongoose.model('University',UniversitySchema);
```

I want to implement `ug.tutionfees` and `pg.tutionfees` in this model class.

Comment: So, you mean to say that you have `ug` is Object and under that `tutionfees` is some key. right?

Comment: yes . i inserted like "ug":{"tutionfees":"$15,000"} how to implement in node js. pls tell me

Comment: please check answer, and let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only these `ug.tutionfees` and `pg.tutionfees` are two different objects you can add into schema as below:

```
ug :{
    tutionfees :{
        type: String
    }
},
pg :{
    tutionfees :{
        type: String
    }
}
```

Check one of my schema structure:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var rbpiSchema = new Schema({
  rbpiId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  last_action: {
    activity: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String
    },
    ut: {
        type: Number
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    }
  },
  ct: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
    default: new Date().getTime()
  },
  ut: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
    default: new Date().getTime()
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('rbpi', rbpiSchema);
```

Comment: thank you.. so much.. i have multiple collections in mongodb . i call that collection name in model class only  and i implemented get function  route.js. nw i implemented one collection . i don't know how to implement multiple collection for same get() function. plz if u know help me

Comment: The question is about to define some object into schema. Currently, you are asking for some different scenario. Anyways, Can you paste some code from route.js and from schema? So, I can understand.

Comment: You can always create on more file and add some schema over there like you mentioned in the question. And just use your file path in `require` to another file where you want to use that schema.

Comment: plz check this  [link]  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473795/how-to-implement-more-than-one-collection-in-get-function . i put my route .js